# I'm can't append a div created in js file inside a <section>, whitch is inside a grid, in my index.html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to create a to-do list and use html/css/js to do it.

- I've created a button, and a text input on HTML.
- Created a function in JS.
- Got both by their id.
- Created a div in JS.
- inserted the the text that I got from text input inside the var that holds the div.
- and tryied to append this div into the section using appenddChild.

When I click the button I can see the div apearing for less than a second inside the section, and it desapears.

```js
function addTask() {
  let userInput = document.getElementById("add-field").value;
  let task = document.createElement("div");
  task.innerText = userInput;
  taskList = document.getElementById("list");
  task.className = "task-bar";
  document.querySelector('#list').appendChild(task);
}
```

```html
<main id="container">

  <section id="entrance">
    <h1>TASKS</h1>
  </section>

  <section id="adding">
    <form id="adding-items">
      <input id="add-field" type="text">
      <button id="send-btn" value="ADD" onclick="addTask()">ADD</button>
    </form>
  </section>

  <section id="list">

  </section>
</main>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `form` element.
So if you click the button, it would refresh the page.

To prevent it, you can use `onSubmit="return false;"`.

`<form onSubmit="return false;" id="adding-items">`

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're using a `<form>` element. Forms have a default behavior that when it contains a button, that button will be used to submit the form, unless the `type` of the button is other than `submit`.

You'll need to stop the default behavior of the form from happening. You do this by preventing the default behavior of the **submit** event.

You do this with [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) inside the event handler.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#adding-items');
const taskList = document.querySelector('#list');
const userInput = document.getElementById("add-field")

function addTask() {
  let userInputValue = userInput.value;
  let task = document.createElement("div");
  task.innerText = userInputValue;
  task.className = "task-bar";
  taskList.appendChild(task);
}

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault(); // Stop the default behavior.
  addTask();
});
```

```html
<main id="container">

  <section id="entrance">
    <h1>TASKS</h1>
  </section>

  <section id="adding">
    <form id="adding-items">
      <input id="add-field" type="text">
      <button id="send-btn" value="ADD">ADD</button>
    </form>
  </section>

  <section id="list">

  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you guys! it worked. I did't know about this defaut behavior from the form.

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer. This will help others with the same question to find the answer.